# How to display a spotify track with custom status?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can i display the playing track in spotify if the user has a custom status?
maybe i need use `presence.activities.map`, but i dont understand how xd

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;

 let convert = require('parse-ms')
 let status = user.presence.activities[0];

let activity = user.presence.activities.find(activity => status.name !== "Spotify" && activity.type !== 'LISTENING')

 if (activity) return message.channel.send("User isn't listening the Spotify.");
     if (status !== null && status.type === "LISTENING" && status.name === "Spotify" && status.assets !== null) {
      let album = status.assets.largeText,
          timeStart = status.timestamps.start,
          timeEnd = status.timestamps.end,
          timeConvert = convert(timeEnd - timeStart);
      
      let minutes = timeConvert.minutes < 10 ? `0${timeConvert.minutes}` : timeConvert.minutes;
      let seconds = timeConvert.seconds < 10 ? `0${timeConvert.seconds}` : timeConvert.seconds;
      
      let time = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
      
      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(0x1ED768)
      .setThumbnail(image)
      .setDescription(`<:Spotify_iconicons:724735015895695450> ${user} listen now [\`${artist} - ${name}\`](${url})\n⠀`)
      .addField(`Album: **\`${album}\`**`, `⠀`, true)
      .addField(`Duration: **\`${time}\`**`, `⠀`, true)
     
      message.channel.send(embed)
      return message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const User = client.users.cache.get("UserID"); // Getting user by ID
    if (!User.presence.activities[0] || User.presence.activities[0].name !== "Spotify") return false // Checking if the user is listening to spotify.
    console.log(`${User.tag} is listening to: ${User.presence.activities[0].state} - ${User.presence.activities[0].details}`) // Logging the artist and the song.
       // Output --> Jakye#0000 is listening to: Sabaton - The Red Baron
```

Example of a Presence in case you want to add more information:

```
  activities: [
    Activity {
      name: 'Spotify',
      type: 'LISTENING',
      url: null,
      details: 'The Red Baron',
      state: 'Sabaton',
      applicationID: null,
      timestamps: [Object],
      party: [Object],
      assets: [RichPresenceAssets],
      syncID: '0ePmfd8y7g4zs3E6ew7pDB',
      flags: [ActivityFlags],
      emoji: null,
      createdTimestamp: 1593080147492
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you very much forhelp, but i get an error "Cannot read property 'presence' of undefined"

Comment: Looks like the User is undefined. Make sure you entered a valid User ID.